# Access Node Environment Variables in Jade file

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I am trying to figure out how to optionally display text in a jade file based on the environment. I can't seem to figure out how to access the `NODE_ENV` variable in my jade file.

In my `index.jade` file I am doing:

```
if process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'
  h1 I am in development mode
else
  h1 I am not in development mode
```

The problem is that `process.env.NODE_env` is `undefined`.

When I try and do: `h1 #{process.env}` outside of the `if` statement, Jade outputs `[Object Object]` onto the page.

When I try and do: `h1 #{process.env.NODE_ENV}` outside of the `if` statement, Jade does not output anything onto the page.

I am not rendering my Jade files on fly, rather I am building them all as "static" files whenever I start the server.

Comment: I didn't do my jade/pug compilation from a .js file, so I instead followed the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44549022/reading-environment-variables-from-pug

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Anything you want to access in the jade template has to be in the locals object sent down from the server.  For something like the process environment, you can do this right when you fire up your app:

```
const express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.locals.env = process.env;  // though you might prefer to clone this instead of setting them equal
```

Then in your jade template you can do

```
#{env.NODE_ENV}
```

**UPDATE**

Adding for direct use, rather than in an express server.

```
const pug = require('pug');

// Compile the source code
const compiledFunction = pug.compileFile('template.pug');

// Render a set of data
console.log(compiledFunction(process.env));
```

That'll log it, but of course you could just as easily write that to an HTML file using `fs` utilities instead.

Comment: What if you're not using a node server, but just using pug to compile static html?

Comment: @Costa that's covered in the docs (https://pugjs.org/api/getting-started.html).  You create the compiled function by compiling the template file and then pass the variables in to that.  I'll post an update.

Comment: I'm just using this one line in my npm scripts: `"watch-pages": "pug -O options.json -w pages/ --out _static-website/"`. There is not node.js code besides that.

Comment: @Costa maybe you should open a new question around that?